# Salesforce-SAP Integration

Tags: integration

I found 3 solution to connect salesforce with SAP.

```
1. Force.com Native Connector - Force.com Connect for SAP R/3
2. Integration Middleware - CastIron,Informatica etc...
3. Custom Integrations - Webservices and Mashups
```

I don't want use third party tool (Middleware) instead want to create own interface which can be customizable to exchange data from salesforce to SAP & viceversa.

Currently I am analyzing two options (Force.com native connector and Custom Integration), but I am not able to decide which will be reliable & flexible for me to develop and implement as no specific documentation available.

Also I found no guidelines available for Native connector Force.com Connect for SAP R/3.

Please guide me to select approach and provide help documentation links specific for Force.com native SAP connector & Custom integration to connect SAP & SF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: be careful when integrating in this way as updates to the system could affect your integration in the future, in these instances its often easier to go for a middleware product that uses crowd-sourcing which will maintain the integration for you. Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: have you found any solution for this or any document reference?

Comment: The Force.com Connect for SAP R/3 is circa 2007

Comment: Have you found a good approach? I'm in the same situation than you. I need to choose an approach that won't be an expensive middleware as we are a small company.

Comment: I am using Cast Iron for my integrations. I know that you do not want to use. If I would decide between 1 and 3, I would decide by Force.com Native Connector and try to use out of the box features.